# Garbage uint64 values from ctypes

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, bsd

I'm trying to read the fields ifi_ibytes/ifi_obytes from the struct if_data64 as described in [this header file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/net/if_var.h).  I've got ctypes working and I can make the sysctl call and I'm getting what seems to be usable information out of it.  However, I'm getting what appears to be total garbage out of the non-zero integers.  For example, I have one interface with 0 bytes received and ~8.5 million bytes transmitted.  However, my python code is saying  0 received and 3,590,592,659,456 bytes transmitted.

I'm copying the approach from [this known to work program](https://github.com/bji/MenuMeters/blob/master/MenuExtras/MenuMeterNet/MenuMeterNetStats.m#L79) and the byte count I'm getting from Python doesn't resemble anything close to the MenuMeter numbers as seen above.  I am using a slightly different sysctl (NET_RT_IFLIST2) which gives 64 bit integers which I've taken into account in my code.

Here's my code:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.util import find_library
from ctypes import sizeof as c_sizeof
import errno

libc = CDLL(find_library('c'), use_errno=True)

# hardcoded macosx constants!
CTL_NET = 4
PF_ROUTE = 17
NET_RT_IFLIST2 = 6

RTM_IFINFO2 = 0x12
IFF_LOOPBACK = 0x8
AF_LINK = 18

class if_data64(Structure):
   _pack_ = 4
   _fields_ = [('ifi_type', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_typelen', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_physical', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_addrlen', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_hdrlen', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_recvquota', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_xmitquota', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_unused1', c_ubyte),
               ('ifi_mtu', c_uint32),
               ('ifi_metric', c_uint32),
               ('ifi_baudrate', c_uint32),
               ('ifi_ipackets', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_ierrors', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_opackets', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_oerrors', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_collisions', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_ibytes', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_obytes', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_imcasts', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_omcasts', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_iqdrops', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_noproto', c_uint64),
               ('ifi_recvtiming', c_uint32),
               ('ifi_xmittiming', c_uint32)]

class if_msghdr2(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('ifm_msglen', c_ushort),
               ('ifm_version', c_ubyte),
               ('ifm_type', c_ubyte),
               ('ifm_addrs', c_int),
               ('ifm_flags', c_int),
               ('ifm_index', c_ushort),
               ('ifm_snd_len', c_int),
               ('ifm_snd_maxlen', c_int),
               ('ifm_snd_drops', c_int),
               ('ifm_timer', c_int),
               ('ifm_data', if_data64)]

class sockaddr_dl(Structure):
   _fields_ = [('sdl_len', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_family', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_index', c_ushort),
               ('sdl_type', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_nlen', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_alen', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_slen', c_ubyte),
               ('sdl_data', c_char * 12)] # for now

MIB_TYPE = c_int * 6
mib = MIB_TYPE(CTL_NET, PF_ROUTE, 0, 0, NET_RT_IFLIST2, 0)

sysctl_buf_len = c_uint(0)

rval = libc.sysctl(mib, 6, None, byref(sysctl_buf_len), None, 0)
if rval != 0:
   raise Exception(errno.errorcode[get_errno()])

sysctl_buf = create_string_buffer(sysctl_buf_len.value)
rval = libc.sysctl(mib, 6, sysctl_buf, byref(sysctl_buf_len), None, 0)
if rval != 0:
   raise Exception(errno.errorcode[get_errno()])

# walk the structure.  you need to know the length from ifm_msglen
idx = addressof(sysctl_buf)
end = idx + sysctl_buf_len.value
while idx < end:
   batch_off = idx - addressof(sysctl_buf)
   ifmsg = cast(c_void_p(idx), POINTER(if_msghdr2))
   if ifmsg.contents.ifm_type != RTM_IFINFO2:
      idx += ifmsg.contents.ifm_msglen
      continue
   if ifmsg.contents.ifm_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK:
      idx += ifmsg.contents.ifm_msglen
      continue
   # 12 bytes to compensate for 32 bit alignment
   sdl = cast(c_void_p(idx + c_sizeof(if_msghdr2) + 12), POINTER(sockaddr_dl))
   if sdl.contents.sdl_family != AF_LINK:
      idx += ifmsg.contents.ifm_msglen
      continue

   print sdl.contents.sdl_data[0:sdl.contents.sdl_nlen]
   print ifmsg.contents.ifm_data.ifi_ibytes, ifmsg.contents.ifm_data.ifi_obytes
   idx += ifmsg.contents.ifm_msglen
```

Comment: Note that 3,590,592,659,456 in decimal is 344,0000,0000 in hex. Perhaps it should have been 344 in hex (836 bytes transmitted, in decimal). The reason could be referring to a memory containing an int32 as an int64, or vice versa.

Comment: I don't know how to do the pointer arithmetic in ctypes like you'd see on line 110 of the reference implementation so I pad it out manually.  I do need some offsetting for alignment as the sockaddr_dl struct does live 12 bytes after if_msghdr2 (as confirmed by the sdl_nlen/sdl_data fields being correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `if_data64`, the `ifi_baudrate` field should be `c_uint64` instead of `c_uint32`. Fixing this should align `ifi_bytes` and `ifo_bytes` to the correct offset. It's also missing the last field, `ifi_lastchange`. This is an 8 byte `timeval32` struct. All together, this explains why `sdl` needed an extra 12 byte offset.

```
class timeval32(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('tv_sec', c_int32), 
                ('tv_usec', c_int32)]

class if_data64(Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [('ifi_type', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_typelen', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_physical', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_addrlen', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_hdrlen', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_recvquota', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_xmitquota', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_unused1', c_ubyte),
                ('ifi_mtu', c_uint32),
                ('ifi_metric', c_uint32),
                ('ifi_baudrate', c_uint64),    # was c_uint32
                ('ifi_ipackets', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_ierrors', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_opackets', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_oerrors', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_collisions', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_ibytes', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_obytes', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_imcasts', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_omcasts', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_iqdrops', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_noproto', c_uint64),
                ('ifi_recvtiming', c_uint32),
                ('ifi_xmittiming', c_uint32),
                ('ifi_lastchange', timeval32)] # was missing
```

Instead of using `cast` with pointers, I'd write the loop using the `from_buffer` method (Python 2.6+) and offsets.

```
buf_offset = 0
while buf_offset < sysctl_buf_len.value:
   msg_offset = buf_offset
   ifmsg = if_msghdr2.from_buffer(sysctl_buf, msg_offset)
   buf_offset += ifmsg.ifm_msglen
   if ifmsg.ifm_type != RTM_IFINFO2 or ifmsg.ifm_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK:
      continue
   sdl_offset = msg_offset + c_sizeof(if_msghdr2)
   sdl = sockaddr_dl.from_buffer(sysctl_buf, sdl_offset)
   if sdl.sdl_family != AF_LINK:
      continue
   print sdl.sdl_data[:sdl.sdl_nlen]
   print ifmsg.ifm_data.ifi_ibytes, ifmsg.ifm_data.ifi_obytes
```